# Blackberry specific Mobile Redirect plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, mobile

**Is there a Wordpress plugin out there, that redirects only Blackberry visitors to a very simple basic something of the site?**

Currently I have a responsive website, a long vertical one with `smoothscroll.js` (Similar to the Nike one). It responds in iOS, Android, and iPad - and while it displays alright in BB (curve 2009), its very hard to read text. I have to support curve 2009 + BB.

*Any suggestions?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one that I know off, however if you wanted to write a script to solve your problem then:

In Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
   var userBrowser = navigator.userAgent;
   var url = "http://forblackberryusers.yoursite.com/";
   if (userBrowser.indexOf("BlackBerry") >= 0)
   {
      if (userBrowser.indexOf("WebKit") >= 0)
      {
         window.location = url;
      }
   }
</script>
```

or alternatively you could be smart and try and create a plugin. In php, I'd imagine it would have something along the lines of:

```
<?php
   $userBrowser = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   $blackberry = strrpos($userBrowser, "blackberry");
   $webkit = strrpos($userBrowser, "webkit");
   $url = "http://forblackberryusers.yoursite.com/";

   if (!($pos_blackberry === false))
   {
      if (!($pos_webkit === false))
      {
         header("Location: " . $url);
      }
   }
?>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This seems like a good suggestion, I'll give it a go - thanks!